# How to assign a List<string> to a ViewBag and use in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I create and assign values to a list of strings in my controller. I want to assign the list of values to a JavaScript variable. How can I do this?

Controller:

```
List<string> fruits = new List<string>();
list.Add('Apple');
list.Add('Banana');
list.Add('Kiwi');
ViewBag.FruitList = fruits;
```

View:

```
var fruitList = '@ViewBag.FruitList';
```

When I run the program `fruitList` comes back as `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]`

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192950/store-a-value-in-viewbag-from-javascript

Comment: Return json from your controller then `$.getJSON()` on the client

Comment: Why does List<> require this but say a ViewBag with a string does not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Way 1:

You can use `Html.Raw()` and `Json.Encode` for it:

```
var fruitList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.FruitList));
```

### Way 2:

you can use `Json.Parse()` in combination with `Html.Raw()` to parse the raw string in to json:

```
var fruitList = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.FruitList)');
```

### Way 3:

you can also use `JsonConvert` class using [NewtonSoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) to serialize it to json:

```
var fruitList = '@JsonConvert.Serialize(ViewBag.FruitList)';
```